# How to use an environment variable from the Lambda CloudFormation resource for python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sdk, aws-cloudformation

This is the relevant part:

```
      Environment:
        Variables:
          NameServers: !GetAtt HostedZone.NameServers
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          import boto3
          var client = boto3.client('route53domains')
          var aws = require('aws-sdk')
          response = client.update_domain_nameservers(
              DomainName='example.com',
              Nameservers=[
                  {
                      'Name': 'get("NameServers")',
                      ]
                  },
              ]
          )
```

So is this the correct way to use the get the names of the Hosted zone name servers for me to change the domain name servers? I don't really know Python at all.

Comment: [How to Set and Get Environment Variables in Python](https://able.bio/rhett/how-to-set-and-get-environment-variables-in-python--274rgt5)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but it should be something like:

```py
          import boto3
          import os  # <-- Added this

          var client = boto3.client('route53domains')
          var aws = require('aws-sdk')
          response = client.update_domain_nameservers(
              DomainName='example.com',
              Nameservers=[
                  {
                      'Name': os.environ['NameServers'],  # <-- Changed this
                      ]
                  },
              ]
          )
```